# Celestial event won't initiate after killing the Lunatic Cultist

Tags: terraria

I have killed the Lunatic Cultist, and the message appeared, "Celestial creatures are invading!!!" But nothing happened. Is my terraria bugged, glitched, or what happened?

Comment: Let's make sure we have all the possible details on this one :  
Was the lunatic cultist boss spawned via a server command ?

Comment: No. I fought the cultists and he spawned. Then I defeated him.

Comment: Have you explored the map from end to end and verified that there are no celestial pillars spawned?

Comment: Have you opened your map to have a look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Celestial Event is unlike most other events that you would be used to, in the way that the creatures from it spawn. Usually an event will spawn the enemies near the player or near the player's original spawn point (the centre of the map) however the Celestial Event does neither of these two.

After you kill the Lunatic Cultist four Celestial Pillars will spawn at even(ish) intervals around the map. The Celestial creatures will spawn near these pillars.

From the centre of the map if you travel left or right you will encounter two of the pillars before reaching the Ocean. The background and music will change when you enter the Celestial zones and you will encounter new, very difficult enemies.

You can ascertain the exact locations of the Celestial Pillars by opening up the map (default <kbd>m</kbd>) and the four pillars should already be marked on the map floating slightly above the surface.

Comment: It should be stated that a glitch does exist which has caused the pillars to spawn much higher, subterranean and even not at all. This glitch is however extremely rare and unlikely.

Comment: @ydobonebi The former two [are not bugs](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Celestial_Tower#Pillar_Spawning_Mechanics) Based on how it determines where to spawn it can spawn from 100 blocks from below the top of the map to nearly 100 blocks below the surface. If it doesn't spawn at all then it is for sure a glitch, but as you've said it's extremely rare and I think it's more likely that OP just hasn't looked at their map and realized it's not like other events.